# How to align div content to center in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a `div` having two `divs` inside as follows.

HTML code:

```
<div style="margin: 20px auto;" align="center">
        <div style="float:left;">
            <input type="button" class="myButton" value="Add"/>
            <input type="button" class="myButton" value="Modify"/>
            <input type="button" class="myButton" value="Delete"/>
        </div>        
        <div>
            <form id = "country_form" method="post">
                <select id="country_name" name = "country_name" style = "position: relative;width:60px;" onChange="return country_change();">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="India">India</option>
                    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
                    <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
                    <option value="UAE">U.A.E</option>
                    <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
                    <option value="USA">U.S.A</option>
                    <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
                    <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
                    <option value="China">China</option>
                </select>&nbsp;
                <select id="country_port" name = "country_port" style = "position: relative;margin-left:5px;width:60px;">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="Macau">Macau</option>
                        <option value="Ningbo">Ningbo</option>
                        <option value="Beijing">Beijing</option>
                        <option value="Shanghai">Shanghai</option>
                        <option value="Guangzhou">Guangzhou</option>
                        <option value="Shenzhen">Shenzhen</option>
                </select>&nbsp;
                <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="submit_value"/>
                <input type="submit" class="myButton" value="Search"/>      
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As i am doing float left to first inner div the outer div is going to left of screen.

So how to make it center.

Please help me to make it possible

jsFiddle: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kbVH2/33/)**

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kbVH2/34/) ?

Comment: You are not defining any `width` to your wrapper element, don't forget to clear your floats as well...

Comment: the css `margin : 20px auto;` works only if your div has a width < 100%;

If you can't set the div width, i think the only possible case is to use flexbox. But flexbot works only on ie11+ (ie10 is buggy)

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps.........

```
<div style="margin: 20px auto; width:80%;" align="center">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XNdJw/